# Get index in an array.filter callback function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array filter with a callback function:

```
array.filter(createPredicateFn(expression, comparator));
```

My call back function is declared as follow:

```
function createPredicateFn(expression, comparator) {
```

How can I get the index of the element inside my createPredicateFn?

Edit:

here is my predicate function:

```
     function createPredicateFn(expression, comparator) {
            var predicateFn;

            if (comparator === true) {
                comparator = angular.equals;
            } else if (!angular.isFunction(comparator)) {
                comparator = function (actual, expected) {
                    if (angular.isObject(actual) || angular.isObject(expected)) {
                        // Prevent an object to be considered equal to a string like `'[object'`
                        return false;
                    }

                    actual = angular.lowercase('' + actual);
                    expected = angular.lowercase('' + expected);
                    return actual.indexOf(expected) !== -1;
                };
            }

            predicateFn = function (item) {
                return deepCompare(item, expression, comparator);
            };

        }
```

Comment: We can't help you without the code for your `createPredicateFn`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your `createPredicateFn()` you have to return another function. This inner function can have up to three parameters:

1. the value of the element
2. the index of the element
3. the Array object being traversed

[(Source: MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Hence the second parameter of your inner function is the index you look for.

A simplistic example could look like this:

```
function createPredicateFn(expression, comparator) {
  return function( val, index, arr ) {
    // do something and return a boolean here
    return index % 2 == 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and get the index however, I can't make my function working (see my edit)

Comment: Your given function never returns a function, but nothing (hence `undefined`). When you want to use a generator function, that generator has to return a function reference, so `filter()` knows, what function to use.

Comment: I'm a bit lost...Could you please rewrite my function with access to the index? I got this function from angularjs filter and I'm not very comfortable with it, that's why I'm not 100% sure of what I'm doing.

Comment: @ncohen The actual function, that determines, whether an entry should stay in the array or get filtered is that `predicateFn()`, right? If so, just return this at the end of the function.

Comment: Got it, I will try that later today! Thanks

Comment: The problem here is that when I call that: array.filter(createPredicateFn(expression, comparator)); I want my createPredicateFn to return what is returned in my function (either "return false;", "return actual.indexOf(expected) !== -1;" or "return deepCompare(item, expression, comparator);" depending on conditions) but in your case, if I put return "function( val, index, arr ) {" in my function, I will automatically get the whole function returned.

Comment: @ncohen Inside your current function, you have at least 3 pointers to function that could be the filter-function. So which should it be?